# Ionic - showing wrong icon

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

I am trying incorporate the icons from [ionicons.com](http://ionicons.com) on my app. I did download of code from github and added to my app, however I have a problem. I define icon class as **ion-alert** and is show a **ion-android-add-circle**. That follow for other icons also. See the images:

A snippet of my code where I set icon with **ion-alert** class
[image: A snippet of my code]

After `ionic serve` command I get this output:[image: After ionic serve command]

Answer (score 1):

I got issue when using both from  `ionicons.com` and `/docs/ionicons/`.
For alert icon, no need to use `ionicons.com`, use warning icon directly from `https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/`

```
 <ion-icon name="warning"></ion-icon>
```

And remove including of `ionicons.min.css` on index.html (important)

So you will never have issues of wrong icon.

Answer (score 0):

If not using the Ionic framework, which includes it already, which is i think what vusan's answer is getting at, then [Ionicons](https://ionicons.com/) recommended [usage](https://ionicons.com/usage) is now:

1. Load its JavaScript in your app or page, `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.0/dist/ionicons.js`
2. Use an ionic web component, `<ion-icon name="warning"></ion-icon>`

And all is happiness.  Definitely better than the old fonts+classes way.